Flutter audio_waveforms onPlayerStatechanged not working
I am using the audio_waveforms package to generate audio waves and play audio.I call the initialise method(in code below) in my initstate but the onPlayerStateChanged listener never gets called.The oncompletion also does not get triggered at all. Am I doing something wrong ?. I have tried everything its just does not get called and seems that portion of the code is totally ignored
class AudioPlayerViewModel extends StateNotifier<AudioPlayerState> {
  final Ref ref;

  AudioPlayerViewModel(this.ref) : super(const AudioPlayerState());

  final recorderController = RecorderController()
    ..androidEncoder = AndroidEncoder.aac
    ..androidOutputFormat = AndroidOutputFormat.mpeg4
    ..iosEncoder = IosEncoder.kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
    ..sampleRate = 44100;
  late PlayerController _playerController;

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    _playerController = PlayerController();
    _playerController.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((playerState) {
      print('Player state changed: $playerState');
      if (playerState == PlayerState.stopped) {
        print('Playback stopped');
        state = state.copyWith(
          isPlaying: false,
        );
      } else if (playerState == PlayerState.playing) {
        print('Playback started');
        state = state.copyWith(
          isPlaying: true,
        );
      }
    });
  }

  Future<String> _generateUniqueFilePath() async {
    final appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final uuid = Uuid();
    final uniqueId = uuid.v4();
    return '${appDocDirectory.path}/audio_recording_$uniqueId.m4a';
  }

  Future<void> startRecording() async {
    await recorderController.checkPermission();

    if (recorderController.hasPermission) {
      final path = await _generateUniqueFilePath();
      print("Recording to path: $path");

      await recorderController.record(path: path);

      state = state.copyWith(
        isRecording: true,
        audioFiles: [...state.audioFiles, path],
      );
    } else {
      print("Permission not granted for recording.");
    }
  }

  Future<void> stopRecording() async {
    final recordedFilePath = await recorderController.stop();
    print("Recording stopped, file saved to: $recordedFilePath");
    final chatBotViewModel = ref.read(chatBotViewModelProvider.notifier);
    await chatBotViewModel.sendAudioMessage(recordedFilePath!);
    state = state.copyWith(isRecording: false);
  }

  Future<void> stopPlayer() async {
    await _playerController.stopPlayer();
    state = state.copyWith(
      currentlyPlayingController: null,
      isPlaying: false,
      currentlyPlayingPath: null,
    );
  }

  Future<void> preparePlayer(String path) async {
    await _playerController.preparePlayer(
        path: path, shouldExtractWaveform: true);
    state = state.copyWith(currentlyPlayingPath: path);
  }

  Future<void> playAudio(String path) async {
    await _playerController.stopAllPlayers();
    state = state.copyWith(isPlaying: true);
    await preparePlayer(path);
    await _playerController.startPlayer();
    state = state.copyWith(
      currentlyPlayingController: _playerController,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    recorderController.dispose();
    _playerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

